# Typescript/Angular 2 - Pass data from one class to another

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a javascript programmer trying to write typescript in angular 2 and need some help:

I have a component, which requires data from another typescript file and then uses it, for example ( I realise this is very contrived, I want to understand how to do something like this):

app.component.ts:

```
import { exampleArray } from './array';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(){
    this.logToConsole(exampleArrary.arrayProperty);
  }

  logToConsole(anything:number[]) {
    console.log(anything);
  }
}
```

array.ts:

```
export class exampleArray {
  arrayProperty = [1, 2, 3];
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Module 'array' has no exported member 'exampleArray'.)
app.component.ts (12,23): Cannot find name 'exampleArrary'.)
```

Is this the right way to approach a problem like this? Is there something I am missing? I have tried 'new'ing the class with no luck

Comment: 1. you're not using the imported Array class anywhere in your app component. 2. Array is the basic type of... arrays. Use another name for your own class. And please don't choose number or string.

Comment: @JBNizet I have edited the question to reflect this

Comment: In order to acces a property of an object, you need to create an object: `const a = new exampleArray(); console.log(a.arrayProperty);`. Your code would be OK if arrayProperty was `static`, i.e. there would be a single exampleArray, linked to the class itself, rather than a new array, linked to each instance of the class. (And if you spelt exampleArray correctly, i.e. not `exampleArrary`). Note that classes, by convention, start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: It is very late,  thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export an object like this:

```
export const array: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```

Then

```
import {array} from "./array";
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is not secure or no sensitive, you can store data in local storage and get from in another place( another class )

```
number = [1, 2, 3];
localStorage.setItem('number',number)
```

you can get data to another class from like this

```
number=localStorage.getItem('number');
```

if you no need to keep data after getting you can remove it from localStorage

```
localStorage.removeItem('number');
```